# MySQL implicitly coerces to wrong collation in view

Tags: mysql, collation

In MySQL 5.6, a view appears to be implicitly coercing `utf8_general_ci` into a `latin1_swedish_ci` instead of the expected `latin1_general_cs`.

**My setup:**

database variables:

```
mysql> show variables like 'col%';
+----------------------+-------------------+
| Variable_name        | Value             |
+----------------------+-------------------+
| collation_connection | latin1_general_cs |
| collation_database   | latin1_general_cs |
| collation_server     | latin1_general_cs |
+----------------------+-------------------+

mysql> show variables like 'char%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | latin1                     |
| character_set_connection | latin1                     |
| character_set_database   | latin1                     |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | latin1                     |
| character_set_server     | latin1                     |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
```

Here's my database and table :

```
CREATE DATABASE `example` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_cs */;

CREATE TABLE `example` (
  `username` varchar(20) COLLATE latin1_general_cs NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_cs;

insert into example values ('user_a');
```

And my view:

```
create or replace view example_view as
select username
from example
where substring_index(user(), '@', 1) = example.username;
```

**My problem:**

When selecting from that view, I get the error:

```
mysql> select * from example_view;
ERROR 1267 (HY000): Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (latin1_general_cs,IMPLICIT) for operation '='
```

When I run the select statement *directly*, it works.

As far as I can tell, NOTHING is set to use `latin1_swedish_ci`. The server, database, table, and column are all set to `latin1_general_cs`.

Here's what MySQL thinks the collation is for each part:

```
mysql> select COLLATION(username) as username, 
    -> COLLATION(user()) as user_func, 
    -> COLLATION(substring_index(user(), '@', 1)) as substr_func
    -> from example;
+-------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| username          | user_func       | substr_func     |
+-------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| latin1_general_cs | utf8_general_ci | utf8_general_ci |
+-------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

So MySQL is trying to convert from `utf8_general_ci` to match the `latin1_general_cs`. But somehow when in the context of a view it decides to use `latin1_swedish_ci` instead.

I'm aware I can just use `convert()` but I'd like to avoid that (partly out of curiosity, partly because lots of `converts()` are going to make for ugly queries).

**My Questions:**

Why is MySQL converting to `latin1_swedish_ci` instead of `latin1_general_cs`? How do I fix that, other than using `convert()` explicitly in the query?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Q: Why is MySQL converting to `latin1_swedish_ci` instead of `latin1_general_cs`?**

Every characterset has a *default* collation. You can use the **`SHOW COLLATION`** statement to see this. An excerpt from the output shows that `latin1_swedish_ci` is the default collation for the `latin1` characterset:

```
Collation             Charset       Id  Default  Compiled  Sortlen  
--------------------  --------  ------  -------  --------  ---------
latin1_german1_ci     latin1         5           Yes               1
latin1_swedish_ci     latin1         8  Yes      Yes               1
latin1_bin            latin1        47           Yes               1
latin1_general_ci     latin1        48           Yes               1
latin1_general_cs     latin1        49           Yes               1
```

We already know that every table has a default characterset and default collation. With the view definition, MySQL is actually creating a table when the query runs.

In the MySQL vernacular, it's called a "derived table".

(As an aside, MySQL does allow some views can be defined with `ALGORITHM=MERGE` instead of the typical and familiar `ALGORITHM=TEMPTABLE`.  With the MERGE algorithm, we get view handling behavior that's more like the behavior of other relational databases, like Oracle and SQL Server.)

When MySQL creates the derived table, it assigns a characterset along with its the default collation.

That's where the `latin1_swedish_ci` is coming from... the default collation for `latin1`.

---

**Q2: How do I fix that, other than using CONVERT() explicitly in the query?**

You can try specifying a collation without the CONVERT() function:

```
CREATE VIEW example_view
AS 
SELECT username COLLATE latin1_general_cs
FROM example
WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(USER(), '@', 1) COLLATE latin1_general_cs = example.username;
```

(If your client characterset is utf8, then you're likely to encounter an error with that syntax, if you don't also have the `CONVERT(... USING ...)`. You can use `COLLATE` in conjunction with the `CONVERT()` function.

```
  CONVERT(USER() USING latin1) COLLATE latin1_general_cs
```

NOTE: I don't have any practical experience with stored views; we use inline views all over the place. But we *never* create stored views, because stored views cause a myriad of problems, *way bigger* and *way more* problems than whatever problems the view definition was a solution for.

Comment: Your CREATE VIEW statement fixed my "Illegal mix of collations" problem when selecting from a view.  The phpmyadmin SQL editor flagged COLLATE as bad syntax in my ALTER VIEW statement, but it ran fine.  Strange that when creating a view, MySQL defaults to a collation that's different from the default collation of the database and server.  It took me hours of research and experimentation to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what exactly you are asking for, but just to avoid the error message you can:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2697e/3

```
create or replace view example_view   as
select username 
from example
where substring_index(user(), '@', 1)  = example.username COLLATE latin1_general_cs;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bf88d/1

Comment: Can you explain why the collation on the comparison defaults to `latin1_general_ci` rather than inheriting the collation of the column being compared (i.e. `example.username`) or the collation of `user()`?

Comment: (It looks the coercion is explained by https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-collation-expressions.html , especially the last paragraph.)

Comment: No I can't. And I am still don't understand why CHARSET and COLLATION are 2 different things in mysql. I would prefer just use the CHARSET. You can check 2nd fiddle to see how mysql settings impact the result of the same query. But I have no explanation why it goes this way.

Comment: Roughly speaking, the **`characterset`** defines the encoding of valid characters, how each "character" is represented in binary, as a series of bits. And the **`collation`** defines the semantics for comparison and ordering of the represented characters. For example, whether or not a lowercase `'a'` is considered to be equal to uppercase `'A'`.  With european/slavic languages, we've got to handle umlauts, accent grave, et al. and whether an "umlaut u" is considered to be equal to a regular "u", etc.It's two separate things because comparison/ordering is separate from the binary representation

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues, but I changed `my.ini`:

```
ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.ini
```

In the file, under `[mysqld]` part I put these lines (which I needed):

```
character-set-server=utf8

collation-server=utf8_hungarian_ci
```